# 2D arrays and their performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance, multidimensional-array

I want to optimize a piece of region-growing code which currently uses two 2D arrays in its algorithm. One 2D array keeps the visited state for each pixel in the 2D texture, and one 2D array holds the "should be masked" boolean for each pixel.

I ran Intel VTune Amplifier XE to profile the performance of the method. Below the most important statistics for a 512x512 image:

- Lookup in the array2D[x][y] takes ~10-15ms
- Writing array2D[x][y] takes ~1-2ms
- Creation and init takes ~8-10ms per array

Furthermore, I'm performing approximately as many reads as I do writes. Creating the 2D array is done in the most basic manner:

```
bool** array2D = new bool*[desc.Width];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < desc.Width; ++i)
    array2D[i] = new bool[desc.Height];

for(unsigned int x = 0; x < desc.Width; x++){
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < desc.Height; y++){
        array2D[x][y] = false;
    }
}
```

I'm searching for better performing structures to hold this information. Code examples, as well as just general ideas (incl. guestimates) are welcome.

Comment: Maybe if it's not an array of pointers to other arrays that are dispersed in the memory, but if it's the single continuous block of memory, it might speed it up a little bit due to caching, but don't expect miracles from it.

Comment: Since your performance measurement is in milliseconds, its kind of difficult to suggest/do optimizations. Run the program for some reasonable amount of time, say for example 100 seconds atleast, and do performance analysis. It might give you better scope for optimization.

Comment: The given measurements were averages, sampled over a (large) number of executions of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try optimizing the performance at the expense of readability by switching from a 2D array to a 1D array. Instead of `array2D[x][y]` you can use `array[x*Height+y]` or `array[x+y*Width]` ([row-major or column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)), depending on your access pattern. This would let you avoid separate allocations.

If the array is large, you could also try packing your booleans into larger integral types. This would make access code somewhat slower, but a considerably smaller footprint might more than compensate for the slower access with better cache performance.

Comment: Using a 1D array instead of 2D, my first lookup is still 15ms, but consequtive lookups dive below 5ms. Is this internal optimization being applied (caches?). Seems this is a step in the right direction. thanks. 

Results for the second option might be shared later.

Comment: @bastijn This is correct -- when subsequent access speeds improve for seemingly identical operations, that usually means a cache hit. CPUs would often pre-read several bytes near the address that you access in anticipation of your next access, and they are often guessing it right; that's when you get a much faster access to a nearby element.

Comment: Accepted this answer as the final. More explaining than the one from synxis (which was not wrong), and the second option turned out to actually make a difference. It is hard to pin numbers as I have added more, but I would say that it makes sense the moment you start working with images (far) larger than 512 cubed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your 2d array in a 1d one:

```
type* array = new type[width * height];
array[x + y * width] = data_at_x_y;
```